# Date Grouping Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Our production cycle time is from 06:00 AM till 06:00 AM. When in a report i want to see the production figures group by date, it is doing the normal grouping that is 00:00 till 23:59. There is an option to put my own formula to group date.

Can anyone please help me what would be the formula for starting the day at 06:00 AM and ending at 05:59 AM.

Answer (score 0):

The grouping formula should look like this:

```
If Hour({Table.DateTimeColumn}) < 6 Then
    DateAdd("d", -1, {Table.DateTimeColumn})
Else
    {Table.DateTimeColumn}
```

This subtracts one day from the date if the time is before 06:00 AM.

If `NULL`-values are possible in the column, then there should also be a check with `IsNull`.

```
If IsNull({Table.DateTimeColumn}) Then
    {Table.DateTimeColumn}
Else If Hour({Table.DateTimeColumn}) < 6 Then
    DateAdd("d", -1, {Table.DateTimeColumn})
Else
    {Table.DateTimeColumn}
```